# Inverse image of a diffeomorphism

Tags: analysis

Let $$f: (0, \infty ) \times (- \pi , - \pi) \to \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus ( (- \infty , 0] \times \{0\})$$

$$f(r, \alpha)=(r \cos \alpha , r \sin \alpha) $$
Find $f^{-1 }(A)$, where

$$A = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus ( (- \infty , 0] \times \{0\}):  (x-\frac{1}{2} )^2+y^2< \frac{1}{4} \}$$

$$(r \cos \alpha-\frac{1}{2})^2+r^2 \sin^2 \alpha < \frac{1}{4} $$
$$r^2-r \cos \alpha< 0 $$
$$r - \cos \alpha< 0$$
Thus
$f^{-1 }(A)= \{(r, \alpha) \in (0, \infty ) \times (- \pi , - \pi): r< \cos \alpha  \}$
It is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, this is correct. I checked this by visualizing, which I find helpful, so here's a way to do that: Note that $A$ is the interior of the circle with radius $\frac{1}{2}$ centered at $(\frac{1}{2}, 0)$. If you do a polar plot of $r < \cos(\alpha)$, that's exactly what you get:

[image: circle]

Which makes sense, because $f$ is exactly the transformation we use when doing polar plots (it takes you from $(r, \alpha)$ space to $(x, y)$ space).

Bonus: If you view the $(r, \alpha)$ space as a rectangle with base running from $(-\pi, \pi)$ and height running from $(0, \infty)$, $f$ can be visualized as taking horizontal slices of the rectangle and wrapping them around to form circular regions.